# how to get a dataframe of row indices for categorical data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Having a dataframe as this one:

```
import pandas as pd
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [6,5], 'b': [4, 3], 'c': [5, 3]} )
mydf.index = [1,2]
mydf    

    a   b   c
1   6   4   5
2   5   3   3
```

How do I locate the row of each data point, to get a dataframe as this one:

```
values = mydf.to_numpy().flatten().tolist()
values = list(dict.fromkeys(values))
values.sort()

[3,4,5,6]

resultdf = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a': [None,None,2,1], 'b': [2, 1,None,None], 'c': [2,None,1,None]} )
resultdf.index= values
resultdf = resultdf.astype('Int64')
resultdf

    a       b       c
3   <NA>    2       2
4   <NA>    1    <NA>
5   2    <NA>       1
6   1    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: How is your input dataframe defined?  What are the meaning of the columns, what are the meaning of the rows, what is considered an observation?   In you expected output are columns equivalent with the input frame?  Are observations considered the index?

Comment: as an analogy 1 ... 2a. columns are customers. 2b. row (index) mean priorities.2c data points  are items with more or less priority for a customer. 3. yes. 4. in the second df de rows (index) are the items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) then [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html#pandas-dataframe-rename-axis) to cleanup axis names:

```
new_df = (
    mydf.stack()
        .reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index=0, columns='level_1', values='level_0')
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     a    b    c
3  NaN  2.0  2.0
4  NaN  1.0  NaN
5  2.0  NaN  1.0
6  1.0  NaN  NaN
```